# Prism RequestNavigate and ViewModel OnPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, telerik, prism-4

I am using the [Telerik RadRibbonView](http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf/ribbonview.aspx) in my WPF 4.5 project. The set up looks like this.

In my Shell I have a RibbonView and a TabControl defined as a regions called “RibbonRegion” and “TabRegion”. The RibbonRegion is basically the menu of the application and the TabRegion holds the main content.

I have also created a module with a View containing a RibbonTab and a RibbonButton. This button is hocked up to a command that sets the DataContext of a RibbonContextTabView and a TabItemView  and registers them in their respective regions. The ContextTab and the TabItem is sharing the same ViewModel. This ViewModel has a propery “IsSelected” that the ContextTab and TabItem are bound to.

```
    if (_regionManager.Regions["RibbonRegion"].Views.Any(v => v.GetType() == typeof(ContextTabView)) && _regionManager.Regions["TabRegion"].Views.Any(v => v.GetType == typeof(TabItemView)))
    {
        _regionManager.RequestNavigate("RibbonRegion", new Uri("ContextTabView", UriKind.Relative));
        _regionManager.RequestNavigate("TabRegion", new Uri("TabItemView", UriKind.Relative));
    }
    else
    {
        ContextTabView contextTabView = _container.Resolve<ContextTabView>();
        TabItemView tabItemView = _container.Resolve<TabItemView>();
        contextTabView.DataContext = tabItemView.DataContext = new ContextTabTabItemViewModel();
        _regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("RibbonRegion", () => contextTabView);
        _regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("TabRegion", () => tabItemView);
    }
```

The first time the Command above is executed the DataContext of the views is set and then they are registered in the regions. This also sets the “IsSelected” property to true. If I change focus to the RibbonTab my ContextTab and TabItem loses focus and the “IsSelected” propery is set to false. If I press the button again the [RequestNavigate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg430861%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx) is executed and once again the property is set to true. Here is my problem. If I do this a third time nothing happens! The RequestNavigate is executed but the property is not set to true and the Views does not regain focus. I am fairly new to PRISM and I am afraid that I am way off here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Based on my understanding, everytime you press the button, the **RequestNavigate** is called for the views which are already active, is this correct? By active I mean that the views are being shown in the regions. Are you setting the **IsSelected** property to "true" inside the **ViewModel** constructor? It seems that you are confused about **Navigation** behavior. Do you want to set focus on a specified control or do you want to switch between **Views** inside each **Region**? Regards.

Comment: Yeah I guess you are right. The **Views** are already active just not focused. I do want to set the property **IsSelected** to true again. But how do I access **IsSelected** in the **ViewModel** from another **ViewModel**? Should I use the [Prism EventAggregator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122(v=pandp.40).aspx)?

Comment: I think I got it. I registered the **ViewModel** in the **Module** `_container.RegisterType<IViewModelB, ViewModelB>();`. Then I got it injected through constructor of ViewModelA `public ViewModelA(IViewModelB viewModelB)
        {
            _viewModelB = viewModelB;
        }` and now I can access the **IsSelected** property when the command is executed.

Comment: That last approach would not be the best loosely coupled communication. **EventAggregator** helps keeping the **ViewModels** decoupled using just weak references. I'm replying back to you now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to keep communication between **ViewModels** in a loosely coupled manner, you could simply use the **EventAggregator** and raise an event from the **Command Button** implementation, which would be then handled by the ***TabItemViewModel***.

The solution you mentioned by adding one **ViewModel** into another would not be ideal as these components would end up working with tight coupling and defining an incorrect situation as **Views/ViewModels** would not depend on another **View**.

Therefore, to accomplish the **EventAgregation** approach, you would need to receive the **EventAggregator** from the container throw constructor on the **View/ViewModel** where the button is clicked, and on each one of the **ViewModels** you would want to ***subscribe*** to that event setting the ***IsSelected*** property inside the ***EventHandler*** method.

You could subscribe to the "***GiveFocusEvent***" event and handle it on the **ViewModels** which would set their ***IsSelected*** property as shown below:

```
public TabItemViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator, ..){
    ...
    GiveFocusEvent setFocusEvent = eventAggregator.Get<GiveFocusEvent>();
    setFocusEvent.Subscribe(SetFocusEventHandler, ThreadOption.UIThread);
}

public void SetFocusEventHandler(){
     // change IsSelected property value..
}
```

The **Event** would be published from inside the ***Button's CommandHandler*** method as follows:

```
this.eventAggregator.GetEvent<GiveFocusEvent>().Publish();
```

Notice that you would need to create and make your "***GiveFocusEvent***" event class inherit from **CompositePresentationEvent**:

```
public class GiveFocusEvent : CompositePresentationEvent<string>{}
```

I hope this helped you,

Regards.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It works perfectly and it’s loosely coupled! I have a stupid follow up question for this. If I create another **Module** that is set up just like the one I described can I **subscribe** to the same event? I’m guessing that all **ViewModels** that is subscribing to this particular event will have its **IsSelected** property set to true therefore I need to create one event class for each **Module**?

Comment: @Dux Yes, you can subscribe to the same event in multiple viewmodels.

Comment: Event Aggregator would also work between different modules. Therefore, every ViewModel that is subscribed to a particular event would execute its EventHandler method. You would raise different events if you want to use different buttons to set the property exclusively on different Views. You can check also for **Subscription filtering** on the **MSDN Prism** chapter you mentioned before. I will appreciate if you could select the answer as Accepted. Regards.